# ASP.NET Identity - Forcing a re-login with security stamp

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

So from [What is ASP.NET Identity's IUserSecurityStampStore<TUser> interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487322/what-is-asp-net-identitys-iusersecuritystampstoretuser-interface) we learn that ASP.NET Identity has a security stamp feature that is used to invalidate a users login cookie, and force them to re-login.

In my MVC app, it is possible for admins to archive users. When arched, they should *immediately* be logged out and forced to log in again (which would then reject them since they're archived).

How can I do this? I understand that the security stamp is the key. The default setup looks like this:

```
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider {
            // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
            // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        }
    });
```

Through experimenting, if I set the validateInterval to something like 1 minute, and then manaully hack a users security stamp in the database, then they are forced to re-login but only after that time period has elapsed.

Is there a way to make this instant, or is it just a matter of setting the interval to a low time period and waiting (or implementing my own `OnValidateIdentity` that checks on every request)

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You stated your options correctly, either low interval/waiting or hooking your own custom `OnValidateIdentity`.

Here's a similar question: [Propagate role changes immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286489/how-do-i-forcefully-propagate-role-changes-to-users-with-asp-net-identity-2-0-1)