# Refresh Signin & Reload claims

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, asp.net-identity-3

I am storing the user selected culture into the user claims and i have a custom RequestCultureProvider that reads this value and set the request culture accordingly.

The application will have a profile page where the user can change his preferences (culture included). After save the data to the database I need to **silently re-signin** the user in order to update his claims.

**Additional info:**

- I'm using IdentityServer4 with AspNet Core 2.0 and Asp.Net Identity
- I'm loading the culture to the claims in the OnTokenValidated event    (client apps). It can also be done in the GetProfileDataAsync (IProfileService) or UserClaimsPrincipalFactory (ASP.NET Core Identity)
- The system is composed by 3 web apps (Idsv4 + app1 + app2). The profile pages are implemented in the app applications.
- With a single web app configured with Asp.NET Identity you can use the method RefreshSignInAsync from the SignInManager to regenerates the user's application cookie, however I need to trigger this process from the client apps (app1 & app2), so no access to SignInManager.
- I tried to use HttpContext.Authentication.ChallengeAsync("oidc") HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync and apparently the authenticate endpoint is invoked however I cannot handle the response and it generates a infinite loop in the MVC action where I'm invoking this code.

So, how can I achieve the silently re-signing with Idsrv4?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force update custom user claims?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004202/how-to-force-update-custom-user-claims)