# How to sign out other user in ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

How can i sign out another user (not the currently logged one) in ASP.NET Core Identity.

I know there is a [`SignOutAsync()`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/5480aa182bad3fb3b729a0169d0462873331e306/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/SignInManager.cs#L194) method in `SignInManager`, but there seems to be no override accepting user as argument. I'm looking for something like:

```
signInManager.SignOutAsync(user);
```

Comment: Have you tried invalidating the Security stamp of the target user. This should invalide his/her session on his/here next http request.

Comment: Does the value of security stamp matter? Or just it should be different than previous security stamp?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

First update the security stamp of that user:

```
await userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user)
```

Then that user won't be noticed the changes until the arrival of the `SecurityStampValidationInterval`. So set it to `Zero` for the immediate logout:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(identityOptions =>
{
   // enables immediate logout, after updating the user's stat.
   identityOptions.SecurityStampValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;
}
```

Update: For ASP.NET Core Identity 2.x, 3.x, 5.x

```
services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
{
    // enables immediate logout, after updating the user's stat.
    options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;   
});
```

Comment: Does this solution apply to asp.net identity 2.0 and above?

Comment: Updated the answer for ASP.NET Core Identity 2.x.

Comment: This `severely impact` is just `one` query to the DB. If that DB is not able to handle it, change it!

Comment: Just to be correct here - Its more than `one` query - counting 5 extra queries on ASP.NET Core 2.X (AspNetUser, AspNetUserClaims, AspNetUserRoles,AspNetRoles, AspNetRoleClaims)

Comment: AFAIK this will result for DB queries for user "changes" for every request of every user, and this will impact all requests to your webapp.

Comment: Suppose you have disabled a user. (s)he should be logged out immediately, otherwise wait for further damages from that user...

Answer (score 1):

I think you might find some *revoke* functionality, which make sign out user forcefully. It is not easily implemented currently as the nature of stateless connection and token-based (or we can say claim-based) authentication.

A revoked user should be accessed to a token validation endpoint in order to check the token valid or not. Until then, (1) the user could be shown as a signed-in, or (2) we need to implement client(app or web) to access to the token endpoint *very* frequently till token expiration or revokation.

SignIn/Out is tighted to token-authorized user identity scope, so that the viable solution is to invalidate a token.

Comment: By token you mean "security stamp"? Something like: `IUserSecurityStampStore.SetSecurityStampAsync(newValue)` ?

Comment: Yes. check out two helpful posts please; http://stackoverflow.com/a/19505060/361100 http://stackoverflow.com/q/24570872/361100