# ASP.NET Identity Core - too many role related queries

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, identity, roles

My project uses role-based authorization and it has over 100 roles. I've noticed that before every action, server queries each user role and it's claims separately. That's over 200 queries before each action. Even an empty controller does this, so I assume this is ASP.NET Identity Core functionality. Is there any way to optimize this?

Thanks in advance.

```
ASP.NET Core web server output (one out of many role queries):

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@__role_Id_0='390'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [rc].[ClaimType], [rc].[ClaimValue]
      FROM [AspNetRoleClaims] AS [rc]
      WHERE [rc].[RoleId] = @__role_Id_0
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@__normalizedName_0='100' (Size = 256)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT TOP(1) [r].[Id], [r].[ConcurrencyStamp], [r].[Name], [r].[NormalizedName]
      FROM [AspNetRoles] AS [r]
      WHERE [r].[NormalizedName] = @__normalizedName_0
```

My Startup.cs class:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies 
                // is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                options
                    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                    .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), x =>
                    {
                        x.UseRowNumberForPaging();
                        x.UseNetTopologySuite();
                    }));

            services.Configure<WebEncoderOptions>(options => 
            {
                options.TextEncoderSettings = new TextEncoderSettings(UnicodeRanges.All);
            });

            services.Configure<AppConfiguration>(
                Configuration.GetSection("AppConfiguration"));

            services.AddIdentity<User, UserRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Password settings
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;

                // Lockout settings
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

                // User settings
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            });

            services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
            {
                // enables immediate logout, after updating the users stat.
                options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;
            });

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                // Cookie settings
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(150);
                // If the LoginPath isn't set, ASP.NET Core defaults 
                // the path to /Account/Login.
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                // If the AccessDeniedPath isn't set, ASP.NET Core defaults 
                // the path to /Account/AccessDenied.
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });

            // Add application services.
            services.AddScoped<IEmailSenderService, EmailSenderService>();
            services.AddScoped<IUploaderService, UploaderService>();
            services.AddScoped<IPdfService, PdfService>();
            services.AddScoped<ICurrencyRateService, CurrencyRateService>();
            services.AddScoped<IViewRenderService, ViewRenderService>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserCultureInfoService, UserCultureInfoService>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
            services.AddHostedService<QueuedHostedService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IBackgroundTaskQueue, BackgroundTaskQueue>();

            services
                .AddMvc(options =>
                {
                    options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;

                    options
                        .RegisterDateTimeProvider(services)
                        .ModelMetadataDetailsProviders
                        .Add(new BindingSourceMetadataProvider(typeof(ListFilterViewModel), BindingSource.ModelBinding));
                })
                .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
                // app.UseMiddleware<StackifyMiddleware.RequestTracerMiddleware>();
            }
            else
            {
#if DEBUG
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
#else
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Default/Error");
#endif

                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapAreaRoute(
                    name: "Hubs",
                    areaName:"Hubs",
                    template: "Hubs/{controller=CompanyAddresses}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Default}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Default}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: is this mvc? what authentication technique are you using?

Comment: Yes, it's a mvc project. I'm using Identity authentication:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Can you update your question with your StartUp.cs class?

Comment: Sure thing. Done.

Comment: Everything seems to be on its place. are you working with UserManager and RoleManager?

Comment: Yes, I've already found a problem, but thanks anyway for taking an interest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out what causes this weird behavior. It's this code segment in my Startup.cs class:

```
services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
{
    // enables immediate logout, after updating the users stat.
    options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;
});
```

Removing it solved my problem. I've been using this to force logout users by updating their security stamp as described here: [How to sign out other user in ASP.NET Core Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41629691/how-to-sign-out-other-user-in-asp-net-core-identity/42389162)

It seems I will have to look for other solution for force logout, but I'm happy that requests are now not generating hundreds of SQL queries.