# ASP.Net Framework 4.8 prevent caching of User.Identity.Name attributes

Tags: .net, vb.net, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, .net-4.8

When I login with a user, log out and sign in again with a different user it seems to retain the previous user details.

This is not the case when in Incognito mode so I assume it is cached.

How can I prevent caching, or is it out of my control?

```
Dim user = User.Identity.Name;

Dim claims = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().Claims.ToList()
    For Each claim In claims
    'Iterate claims
```

Comment: What method does it use to log out?

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity SignInManager.SignOutAsync()

Comment: Have you tried deleting the cookie too? [ASP.NET Core Identity 2.0 SignoutAsync is not logging out user if the user signed in with Google](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55491003/1115360)

Comment: Yeh we do delete it. I think the problem is because our app opens tabs to switch to other apps. I will add a safeguard in as I am unsure if I will get to the bottom of this. Thanks

Comment: Maybe [How to sign out other user in ASP.NET Core Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41629691/how-to-sign-out-other-user-in-asp-net-core-identity) has an answer that'll work for your situation.