# ASP.NET Core - Authentication - Remember me not persisting

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

When I wrote my asp.net core authentication, it did not require the "Remember Me" functionality and this is how I implemented my auth (sliding expiration of 30 mins):

**Startup.cs**

```
var roleStore = new CustomRoleStore();
var userPrincipalFactory = new CustomUserPrincipalFactory();

services.AddSingleton<IRoleStore<ApplicationRole>>(roleStore);
services.AddSingleton<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>>(userPrincipalFactory);

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options => {
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = 30;
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.SlidingExpiration = true;
}).AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
[HttpPost("Login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserLogin model)
{
    // If the model is valid, then attempt a login.
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            // Wait for the result for sign in.
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

            // If the call was successful, then update the last sign in.
            if (result.Succeeded)
                return Json(new { success = true, errorcode = 0, result = true });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             return Json(new { success = false, errorcode = 115 });            
        }
    }

    // Return bad request response.
    return BadRequest(new { success = false, errorcode = 111 });
}
```

Other note, I've implemented my own custom user store and role store, who's signatures look as follows:

**CustomUserStore class**

```
public class CustomUserStore : IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, IUserPasswordStore<ApplicationUser>, IUserLoginStore<ApplicationUser>, IUserLockoutStore<ApplicationUser>,  IUserPhoneNumberStore<ApplicationUser>, IUserTwoFactorStore<ApplicationUser>
```

**CustomRoleStore class**

```
public class CustomRoleStore : IRoleStore<ApplicationRole>
```

I now have the need to implement the remember me functionality, and by changing the one option you'd expect to work (param to PasswordSignInAsync - IsPersistent was always false, now it can be true), my requests still return authenticated along with a auth cookie but subsequent requests return 401 as they cant pick up the auth cookie? (*HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false*).  I've seen articles such as this:

[How do I forcefully propagate role changes to users with ASP.NET Identity 2.0.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286489/how-do-i-forcefully-propagate-role-changes-to-users-with-asp-net-identity-2-0-1/24317054#24317054)

But they seem to do their authenticate in a slightly different way than I have (I've implemented my own middleware to handle authentication):

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),
    },
    SlidingExpiration = false,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
});
```

Can anyone suggest how to get the persistent cookie working?  Can I swap out my code (at the top) for this code (just above)?  The only difference from this working to not working is the one param *IsPersistent* changing from always false to sometimes true now.

Please help and thanks in advance for any pointers!